# Creator of the instance

Tags: users, metadata

I am trying to figure out how to get information about who is the creator of an instance in the GCP.

The use case: I wish to build a certain automation, and one of the requirements is to get information about who is the creator of the instances inside a project.

The problem: I couldn’t figure out how to get information regarding who created the machine, I couldn’t find any information in the UI or through the GCP documentation and API.
Currently the idea is to put alabel by using startup script that will determine who created the instance, however many users creates the instances through the UI and not by a script api or automation.

The question: what are the best practices for this use case? or is there another way to get or set this information?